# Javascript statements not executed when placed before a javascript interface method call on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm trying to change the text of a button using jquery before calling a javascript interface method on android. But this statement does not get executed. Here is the code.

```
$("#send_btn").click(function() {
    if(sendto_number_flag == 1 && sendto_msg_flag ==1 ) {
        $(this).html("Sending...");
        //above statement gets executed after the Java.sendSMS gets executed.
        //I have tried with other statements like .addClass() .hide(), nothing works

        var output = Java.sendSMS($("#sendto_number").val(), $("#sendto_msg").val());
        //above statement executes fine and returns valid data
        if(output == "true") {
            $(this).html("Sent Successfully");
        }
        else if(output == "Network Error"){
            $(this).html("Check Connection and Retry");
        }
        else {
            $(this).html("Check Details and Retry");
        }
    }
});
```

HTML Tag

```
<button type="button" class="button button_red" id="send_btn" value="Send">Send</button>
```

Comment: When are you registering the click handler? Is the button already in the HTML or is it being added dynamically later? If not, try `$("#send_btn").on('click', function(){...});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some delay for `java.sendSMS` call. Something like this.

```
   $("#send_btn").click(function() {
    if(sendto_number_flag == 1 && sendto_msg_flag ==1 ) {
    $(this).html("Sending...");
    //above statement gets executed after the Java.sendSMS gets executed.
    //I have tried with other statements like .addClass() .hide(), nothing works

    var Variables = {};
    Variables.$obj = $(this);
    Variables.ResizeTimer = setTimeout(
     function(){
    var output = Java.sendSMS($("#sendto_number").val(), $("#sendto_msg").val());
    //above statement executes fine and returns valid data
    if(output == "true") {
        $(Variables.$obj).html("Sent Successfully");
    }
    else if(output == "Network Error"){
        $(Variables.$obj).html("Check Connection and Retry");
    }
    else {
        $(Variables.$obj).html("Check Details and Retry");
     }    
    },1000);
   }
 });
```

Comment: this works, thanks! Although I tested with jquery .delay() earlier.